# Is it possible to add another class to a django-bootstrap-ui template tag

Tags: django, bootstrap-ui

In my django project, I'm using `django-bootstrap-ui 0.5.1`.

I have it in my `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` variable, as well as installed in my virtual environment via my `requirements.txt` file. I've confirmed everything is working by using a basic `{% container %}` tag and its child tags `{% row %}` and `{% column xs="8" sm="6" md="4" lg="3" %}`, for example.

My question is this:

If `{% container %}` renders the following code:

```
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

How can I add another class to that div, alongside `'container'`, so that the output looks like:

```
<div class='container custom-class'>
</div>
```

I've read the documentation and surprisingly didn't see anything about that, which makes me think the answer may be right in front of me and I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to bend this library to do what I want, it's much easier to customize the `{% render_table %}` function of django-tables2.

`$ pip install django-tables2` and read the docs [here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).